# Boolean makes pixelated edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, topology, subdivision-surface

[image]
[image]

**Problem:** I'm making a brake-caliper, and I wanted to cut out these engraved shapes from the brake surface using boolean modifier. It first crossed my topology, which I thought creating the mistake, so I changed that the rotation angle and number of arrayed object are matching and they never cross each other. The problem still occurs. I've watched a Blender tutorial of a brake caliper where the guy makes it with exactly this method and it works for him. I'm stuck because I don't know what am I doing wrong.
I've had a similar question in the past where my topology was messy and I thought at the end that was the cause. I've also tried to apply the subdivision on the caliper itself - result was the same. The cutting objects go through the brake and come out on the other side.

**Question:** How could I use the boolean difference in this case to just simply cut out these objects? How's it possible that the same method works in the tutorial and not for me?

Comment: please show your wireframe, show the tuto video, maybe share your file... your topology must be bad

Comment: https://youtu.be/WAAZzcsM-_Q?t=154 this is the tutorial I was referring to, and I've been organizing the boolean objects the same way. In the meatime though, I figured if I switch off 'shade smooth', it doesn't do it. Can it be that 'shade smooth' in certain cases cannot do boolean operations nicely?

Comment: you need to take a look at your wireframe once you've booleaned, the boolean object and your topology before and after boolean are not the same as the one in the video